# I want to save quantized int8 weights from a convolutional neural network, are my code edits in c correct?

Tags: c, conv-neural-network

Here is a post I made on the GitHub page: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/1405#issuecomment-927394677

Here is all the source code: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo2_light/tree/781983eb4186d83e473c570818e17b0110a309da/src

The closing bracket mistake is easy to fix. I noticed that I got outputs when I added an & to the multipliers. Is & the correct pointer for structs? I put the function in additionally.c, referenced it in additionally.h, and officially referenced it in main.c.

```
void save_weights_int8(network net, char *filename, int cutoff)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Saving weights to %s\n", filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if(!fp) file_error(filename);

    int major = 0;
    int minor = 1;
    int revision = 0;
    fwrite(&major, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&minor, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&revision, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(net.seen, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < net.n && i < cutoff; ++i){
        layer l = net.layers[i];
        if(l.type == CONVOLUTIONAL){
            //save_convolutional_weights(l, fp);
    int num = l.n*l.c*l.size*l.size;
    fwrite(l.biases, sizeof(float), l.n, fp);
    fwrite(l.weights_int8, sizeof(uint8_t), num, fp);

    fwrite(&l.weights_quant_multipler, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&l.input_quant_multipler, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: "*are my code edits in c correct?*". The way to answer that question is to write and run test cases for your own code. Have you done that? Did it show any problems?

Comment: `fwrite` takes an array of elements as its first argument. I assume, for example, that `l.weights_quant_multiplier` is a `float`. Prefixing the ampersand to this member takes its address, which is a pointer to that object (or an array of length 1). Without studying the larger context, I would say that the way you wrote the code (with the `&`) is fairly standard. You may have been ignoring a compiler error of converting a `float` to and `int`, where the compiler was warning that you were converting some float to a pointer. Might want to watch for compiler errors.

Comment: I see no glaring errors, but you haven't provided an [mre] so it's impossible to know. One thing you might consider, instead of `sizeof(<type>)`, do `sizeof(<variableName>)`. For example, `fwrite(&major, sizeof(major) ... `. That way, if `major` ever changes types, you don't need to edit the `fwrite` line also.

Comment: Correction: watch for compiler *warnings*

Comment: Also, particularly if `network` is a large struct, consider passing a `const network*` to your function instead. As is, a copy of your struct is being (unnecessarily) made every time this function is called.

Comment: One thing to think about when storing data: how long does it have to be kept?  Binary formats like you're creating here have one significant long-term drawback: you can't really modify the format by adding a field or even changing the size of a field without having to rewrite a lot of code.  Text-based formats such as JSON have the advantage of being extensible without necessarily invaliding existing code.  Text-based formats also can be much easier to develop, debug, and test.  With JSON, "Hey, ^%???y$ isn't a valid value here!" is painfully obvious.  You don't get that with binary data.

Comment: (cont) Of course that comes at the cost of performance and storage.